# Can't get my js array in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my function:

```
function browsepage_from(starting_node)
{
    //record the properties of the object
    var account_to_rec = new Array();
    var property_name
    var properties = $(starting_node).children('div').children("p").each(function(){
        property_name = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        account_to_rec[property_name] = $(this).html();

    });
    //push the object with properties newly created into a global variable

    to_save.push(account_to_rec);

    //check if children
    if($(starting_node).children('ul'))
    {
        $(starting_node).children('ul').children("li").each(function(){
            browsepage_from($(this))

        });
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Nothing fancy...

`to_save` is a global variable:

```
 to_save = new Array();
```

But in the console then my array looks something like this:

```
[[]


account_action
        "none"

account_code
        "000000"
bla bla

[]


account_action
        "none"

account_code
        "600000"
bla bla

]
```

If I use the JSON.stringify (on the finished to_save or in the recursive on each account_to_rec) I just get empty brackets as a result...

How is that?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablu error here

```
var account_to_rec = new Array();
```

and later you try to use it as object at

```
property_name = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

account_to_rec[property_name] = $(this).html();

maybe

```
 var account_to_rec = {};
```

???